# Delphi OOP Methods

Tags: oop, delphi

How can I change (If possible) a value in a class, whilst inside another class procedure. Example:

```
Class1 : Class
Private
Random : Integer;
public
end;

Class2 : Class
Private
Public
Procedure DoSomething();
end;

Procedure Class2.DoSomething();
Begin
//Do Something
If ... then
Change Random to ...
end;
```

Comment: This is explained in the documentation. What part of that did you not understand?

Comment: Maybe you did not yet read the documentation about [Visibility of Class Members](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Classes_and_Objects#Visibility_of_Class_Members)

Comment: Your code does not demonstrate anything which you are asking about. You're talking about (presumably) class methods and their visibility, but your code isn't related to a class at all. Also, it's not even valid syntax.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The thing I don't understand Is more specific but I thought If I learned the basics it would help. What I really want to know is if I have two classes, c1 and c1, and I'm inside c1.procedure ((just an example)), How can I change a value in c2. Can I even do this?

Comment: That makes no sense to me

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Is the edited question any better?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  I think this might what I'm trying to ask: Can I only edit an instantiated objects value rather than the classes value. e.g  Class1.Ex.Random := ...

Comment: There's a difference between instance variables and class variables. A single variable has to be one or the other.

Comment: the short answer: move 'Random' into the public section!

Answer (score 1):

It depends. You first have to think of the reason why the visibility is separated. `private` methods are intended for use within a class, while `public` methods are intended for use outside of a class.

In your particular example, you are not referencing a class. Instead, I will use your example to demonstrate the following:

```
type
  TMyObject = class(TObject)
  private
    FNumber: Integer;
    function GetNumber: Integer;
    procedure SetNumber(Input: Integer)
  public
    property Number: Integer read GetNumber write SetNumber;
  end;

function TMyObject.GetNumber: Integer;
begin
  Result := FNumber;
end;

procedure TMyObject.SetNumber(Input: Integer);
begin
  FNumber := Input;
end;
```

As you can see, I've added a property called `Number` which uses `GetNumber` to obtain the value and `SetNumber` to assign it. Use of such methods is almost always coupled with the use of a property in this manner.

Coming back to your original question, as I said, it depends. Your property setter might perform some additional code than just assigning the value, for example. In such a case, from within your class, you may need to set this value through its private `FNumber` field instead, so that the additional setter code isn't called.

So in short, the answer is no. It is not *absolutely* necessary to access private members through getters and setters *from within the class*. However, *from outside the class*, then yes, it will be necessary.

On the other hand, you *could* also declare the member under `strict private`, which would force the class member to *only* be visible from within the class itself, and not from anywhere else in the same unit.

[Read more here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Classes_and_Objects#Visibility_of_Class_Members) about visibility of class members.

Comment: Didn't you mean "from outside the unit" rather than "from outside the class" :)? Delphi has that `private` specifier access hole within the same unit (which can be fixed by `strict private` specifier).

Comment: Because it's not "necessary". You can access private fields of a different class from the same unit, even in recent versions of Delphi I bet, can't you?

Comment: @Victoria That's why I referenced the documentation for OP to learn more. Surely there's no need to completely recite the entire documentation here. And yes, private members *can* be accessed from within the same unit by design, but it's not considered good practice.

Comment: Sure. I agree it's no good to access fields from another class in the same unit. This "cheat" can still be useful e.g. for hiding methods of "subcomponents" (like grid headers) that should stay hidden to users (sort of `CalcHeaderRect` methods that are called only from the grid, not by the user).

Comment: O.. K.. Someone mind explaining why they converted their up-vote into a down-vote?

Comment: @JerryDodge-get used with stackoverflow. maybe one day stackoverflow will list who voted (up/down) :) PS: i up-voted to compensate. Your answer is good.

Comment: @JerryDodge:  The d/v wasn't mine and I just had a similar thing happen to another of mine a few minutes ago.  Anyway, do you think you could transplant `strict protected` and the point about strict private vars not showing up in autocomplete into your answer, then I'll delete my answer and u/v yours.

Answer (score 1):

`strict private` and `strict protected`
declarationsection were introduced in D2007.  Members declared in a
`strict private` section are **not** accessible from other classes even in the
same unit, as this example shows:

```
type
  TMyClass = class
  private
    MyPrivateField : Integer;
  strict private
    MyStrictPrivateField : Integer;
  public
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyClass : TMyClass;
begin
  MyClass := TMyClass.Create;
  MyClass.MyPrivateField := 0;       //  compiles ok
  MyClass.MyStrictPrivateField := 1; // does not compile
  //  fails with E2361, "Cannot access private symbol TMyClass.MyStrictPrivateField
end;
```

Note that not only does this fail to compile, but in Seattle at least,
`MyStrictPrivateField` does not show up in the autocomplete list for
TMyClass (with the insertion point in FormCreate), unlike `MyPrivateField`,
which does.